# Is there an update manager for Kubuntu?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, update-manager

Is there a default Update Manager for Kubuntu? If there isn't can I install the Ubuntu Update Manager?

I know I can use

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but sometimes I get something like:

```
0 to install 0 to remove, 0 new, 0 upgraded and 3 not upgraded
```

Any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.. what are the packages that are being put on hold?.

Comment: I'm not sure. It doesn't tell me.

Comment: @Seth to see on-hold packages the best and universal way is `dpkg --get-selections | grep on-hold`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Kubuntu & Muon**

Kubuntu is an [Ubuntu derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives). Information for Kubuntu can be found on the [Kubuntu homepage](http://www.kubuntu.org/). The [Kubuntu 11.10 release notes](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/11.10-release) says:

> Muon Suite 1.2
>
> The Kubuntu team is proud to present our new suite of tools for
>   installing and managing software. Installing of .deb packages,
>   updating, and software management is all part of this new, integrated
>   suite, specifically designed to work with Debian style package
>   management...

The [kubuntu-desktop package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/kubuntu-desktop) is recommending (installing as default):

- muon, package manager for KDE
- muon-installer, utility for browsing, installing, and removing applications
- muon-notifier, update notifier for KDE

The package [muon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/muon) is also recommending the muon-updater, an update manager for KDE.

The latest information of the Muon can be found from the [developer's blog](http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/).

**Apt - upgrade and dist-upgrade**

The "not upgraded" packages could need to install some new packages. The "upgrade" action can't do this.

The apt manual page (`man apt-get`):

upgrade will

> upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
>   currently installed...under no circumstances are currently installed
>   packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and
>   installed. New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be
>   upgraded  without changing the install status of another package will
>   be left at their current version...

dist-upgrade will

> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also
>   intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of
>   packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it
>   will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of
>   less important ones if necessary.

So, the `apt-get dist-upgrade` command may remove some packages...

Answer (score 6):

Update manager for Kubuntu is called `muon-updater` and I believe it's installed by default. Just press Alt-F2 and start typing 'muon-updater' there

Answer (score 0):

Not always is install by default. I experienced that when you install a brand new (not upgrading from ubuntu) kubuntu the muon update manager is not install by default but only the muon discover. So I resolve this by going to the muon discover and in the search box type Muon you will see that the updater has to be install manually. Just press the install button for the muon software center. You will see the updater will get installed as well.

Furthermore if you want to get the latest update just go to left-lower corner (the k button) and click over there go to application-system-Sofware Updates and the updates will be prompted for you. Just follow the instructions.